# How $X=y^b$ distributes if $f(y)=aby^{b-1}e^{-ay^{b}}$ , $y\geq0$.

Tags: probability-distributions

How $X=y^b$ distributes if $f(y)=aby^{b-1}e^{-ay^{b}}$ , $y\geq0$.
(Weibull distribution)

It would be great if you can elaborate on the calculation.

Thanks :D

Comment: *It would be great if you (could) elaborate on* what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $X=y^b$ is an monotonically increasing function for $y\geq 0$, therefore,

pdf of $X$ is $$g(x)=f(y)|\frac{dy}{dx}|=f(x^{1/b})\frac{x^{(\frac{1-b}{b})}}{b}, x\geq 0$$

See [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables)